# I want to display Position Name as "New Position" and "Old Position" in two columns but in one row with respect to their creation date in Oracle HRMS

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * 
  from (
        select distinct 
              papf.employee_number
            , papf.full_name/*, pap.name*/
            , pg.name "Grade"
            , MAX(pap.creation_date) AS "Maximum Date"
            , MIN(pap.creation_date) AS "Minimum Date"
            , CASE WHEN max(pap.creation_date) = (pap.creation_date) 
                   THEN pap.name 
                   ELSE null END AS "New Position"
            , CASE WHEN min(pap.creation_date) = (pap.creation_date) 
                   THEN pap.name 
                   ELSE null END AS "Old Position"
          from per_all_positions pap
             , per_all_assignments_f paaf
             , per_all_people_f papf
             , per_grades pg
          where paaf.position_id = pap.position_id
          and paaf.person_id = papf.person_id
          and paaf.grade_id = pg.grade_id
          and papf.employee_number = 00871
          and papf.effective_end_date = '31-DEC-4712'
          and pg.name IN ('SVP', 'EVP I', 'EVP II', 'SEVP I', 'SEVP II')
          --and paaf.effective_end_date = '31-DEC-4712'
          group by papf.employee_number 
                 , papf.full_name
                 , pap.name
                 , pg.name
                 , pap.creation_date
       )



    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER FULL_NAME   Grade   Maximum Date    Minimum Date    New Position    Old Position
1   00871   Mr. Tahir Mahmood Afzal Raja    SVP 4/9/2014 3:44:22 PM 4/9/2014 3:44:22 PM Area Manager.1.MBL - Area Office Islamabad II   Area Manager.1.MBL - Area Office Islamabad II
2   00871   Mr. Tahir Mahmood Afzal Raja    SVP 7/24/2013 9:57:35 AM    7/24/2013 9:57:35 AM    Branch Manager.1.MBL - Bahria Town Branch, Rawalpindi   Branch Manager.1.MBL - Bahria Town Branch, Rawalpindi
```

> As you can see the output it shows new and old positions in two rows
>   and repeating it, so please help me how to do what I want ? This query
>   is of oracle HRMS and written in PL/SQL developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query are good but you forget wrap `CASE ...` with max and delete grouping by `pap.creation_date`. If you do it you will get what you need. But I d like to use aggregate function `MAX() keep (first)`. I write code with it

```
select * 
  from (
        select distinct 
              papf.employee_number
            , papf.full_name/*, pap.name*/
            , pg.name "Grade"
            , MAX(pap.creation_date) AS "Maximum Date"
            , MIN(pap.creation_date) AS "Minimum Date"
            , MAX(pap.name) KEEP (dense_rank FIRST order by pap.creation_date DESC) AS "New Position"
            , MIN(pap.name) KEEP (dense_rank FIRST order by pap.creation_date) AS "Old Position"
          from per_all_positions pap
             , per_all_assignments_f paaf
             , per_all_people_f papf
             , per_grades pg
          where paaf.position_id = pap.position_id
          and paaf.person_id = papf.person_id
          and paaf.grade_id = pg.grade_id
          and papf.employee_number = 00871
          and papf.effective_end_date = '31-DEC-4712'
          and pg.name IN ('SVP', 'EVP I', 'EVP II', 'SEVP I', 'SEVP II')
          --and paaf.effective_end_date = '31-DEC-4712'
          group by papf.employee_number 
                 , papf.full_name
                 , pg.name
       )
```